# How to import ZeroMQ into Unity engine?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, zeromq

I am attempting to import the ZeroMQ library for a project in Unity.  I am using `C#` and Visual Studio for editing.  I used NuGet to import ZeroMQ into Visual Studio, but when I try to run the game I get the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ZeroMQ' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\<me>\OneDrive\Documents\UrBalls\Assets\Scripts\PlayerController.cs 4   Active
```

The controller file is from a tutorial:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using ZeroMQ;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();     
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hey");
        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {        
    }
}
```

How do I get the compiler to see the package?  Appreciated!

Comment: Okay, this was unexpected. I used a popular ZeroMQ library from NuGet, but when installed into Unity it did not include the files in the `lib` directory.  I installed that and installed the from from [clrzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq) and it worked.

Comment: Also, apparently, Unity has outdated .NET support.  I still don't have an answer on this one.

Comment: Have you gotten an answer yet? I could use it too.

Comment: I didn't get an answer here, but one of my engineers found a work-around.  It was really challenging so we abandoned it.  I'll ask him to post here when he gets a chance.  Good luck to you!

Comment: That would be awesome. I'd love to see a ZeroMQ plugin for Unity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test if this actually works, but I was able to get past the error you have here...

1) If you installed the top result from NuGet (the metadings package), uninstall it and try using the 'clzmq' package (or 64-bit version).

2) Copy the DLLs from: 
'C:\Users\.nuget\packages\clrzmq\2.2.5\lib' &
'C:\Users\.nuget\packages\clrzmq\2.2.5\content' 
 to the 'Assets' folder of your Unity project.

3) In your script, switch 'using ZeroMQ;' to 'using ZMQ;'

You should be able to run at this point.

I did not try copying the DLLs from the first 'ZeroMQ' package by metadings, so you can try that if you like. I would try clzmq first, if it doesn't suit your needs then give metadings another shot. You will have to also configure Unity with 4.0 framework support to use the metadings package.

UPDATE:
I ended up testing this. I had to use the x64 version, but it works. Here's the complete script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Text;
using ZMQ;

public class mqtest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hey");
        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            print("space key was pressed");
            string endpoint = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555";

            // ZMQ Context and client socket
            using (ZMQ.Context context = new ZMQ.Context())
            using (ZMQ.Socket client = context.Socket(SocketType.REQ))
            {
                client.Connect(endpoint);
                string request = "Hello";
                client.Send(request, Encoding.UTF8);
            }
        }
    }
}
```